# angularJS ngDisabled executes function before ng-repeat loads

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using an API to populate a `$scope.var` via `$http`, taking that `$scope.var`.

I have a nested `ng-repeat`

html:

```
<tr ng-repeat='(chore,details) in choreList'>
  <td>
    <div class="btn-group">
      <button ng-repeat="user in users" class='btn group-item' ng-click="addChoreDetail(chore, user.name)" title="{{user.name}}" ng-disabled="checkAddabilityChoreDetail(chore, user.name)">{{chore}}</button>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
```

js:

```
$scope.checkAddabilityChoreDetail = function(inputChore,inputName){
  console.log(inputChore);
}
```

I'm unaware in Angular how to get the ngDisabled to wait to send the chore variable until the repeat actually happens.

I'm getting `undefined` in my console log for the request time of the `get choreList` and I'm not sure how to make it wait for my object to be populated with data.

Comment: Where does 'chore' come from?

Comment: You have ng-repeat taking your arrays from $scope.choreList and $scope.users. Make sure that you are populating these scope variables via your API...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use **promises** for async operations where you don't know when it will be completed - http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$q .

Promises are "**interface for interacting with an object that represents the result of an action that is performed asynchronously, and may or may not be finished at any given point in time**".

Comment: Here is a good example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21097677/using-a-promise-for-retrieving-data-inside-angular-directive

Comment: I think Andrew doesn't need the $q service as he stated that he uses a $http service, he already uses a .then callback so the problem shouldn't be the request itself. My suspicion falls to angular digests as it seems the ng-disabled function is fired when there's no chores loaded in ng-repeat. This should be no problem if there's a simple condition in the checkAddabilityChoreDetail. Upon putting chores on scope, the function should be invoked again, already with the chores. However, more code would be nice...

Comment: I ended up making a new scope and handling the scope population in the promise of my dependency. And then using that new scope to do the ng-repeat. Issue resolved :)